# How to get folder name, in which given file resides, from pathlib.path?

Tags: python, filenames, python-os, pathlib

Is there something similar to `os.path.dirname(path)`, but in pathlib?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

It looks like there is a `parents` element that contains all the parent directories of a given path.  E.g., if you start with:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path('/path/to/my/file')
```

Then `p.parents[0]` is the directory containing `file`:

```
>>> p.parents[0]
PosixPath('/path/to/my')
```

...and `p.parents[1]` will be the next directory up:

```
>>> p.parents[1]
PosixPath('/path/to')
```

Etc.

`p.parent` is another way to ask for `p.parents[0]`.  You can convert a `Path` into a string and get pretty much what you would expect:

```
>>> str(p.parent)
'/path/to/my'
```

And also on any `Path` you can use the `.absolute()` method to get an absolute path:

```
>>> os.chdir('/etc')
>>> p = pathlib.Path('../relative/path')
>>> str(p.parent)
'../relative'
>>> str(p.parent.absolute())
'/etc/../relative'
```

Comment: I don't know what a "shared folder" is.  My advice would be to try it and see if it works.  If it doesn't work and you require further assistance, your best option is probably to post a new question (because comments aren't a great place for extended questions and answers).

Comment: For some reason, `p.parent[0]` and `p.parent[1]` doesn't work on Macs because indexing is not supported. Use `p.parent` for current directory and use `p.parent.parent` to go up one directory.

Comment: @OliverOliver `p.parents[0]`, with the `s`.

Comment: I would add the option `p.parent.resolve()` to get the resolved absolute path.

Comment: Use ```p.parent.name``` to get the parent directory's name without the entire path

Comment: Why doesn't `parents[-1]` work? Any other way to get the last parent?

Comment: `parents[-1]` works just fine, but will always (under Linux, at least) return `/`, because that's always the last parent.

Comment: @larsks - It doesn't work at all for me. It raises an `IndexError`

Comment: @AlaaM. if you are seeing unexpected behavior, you may want to open a new question, and provide the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @larsks nah it's just not supported

Answer (score 10):

### summary

```py
from pathlib import Path
file_path = Path("/Users/yuanz/PycharmProjects/workenv/little_code/code09/sample.csv")
```

##### 1. get dir path

```py
file_path.parent
# >>> /Users/yuanz/PycharmProjects/workenv/little_code/code09
```

##### 2. get filename

```py
file_path.name
# >>> sample.csv
```

##### 3. get file type

```py
file_path.suffix

# >>> .csv
```

##### 4.add new file in this dir path

```py
file_path.parent.joinpath("dd.png")
```

Answer (score -7):

I came here looking for something very similar. My solution, based on the above by @larsks, and assuming you want to preserve the entire path except the filename, is to do:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path('/path/to/my/file')
>>> pathlib.Path('/'.join(list(p.parts)[1:-1])+'/')
```

Essentially, `list(p.parts)[1:-1]` creates a list of Path elements, starting from the second to n-1th, and you join them with a '/' and make a path of the resulting string. *Edit* The final  +'/' adds in the trailing slash - adjust as required.

Comment: My only issue with this solution is that it's assuming '/' is the path splitter.  Which it IS if you're in unix, but it's not if you're in Windows...I was looking for a more 'elegant' solution since my issue which is the same requires OS independence...

Comment: That's why I wrapped everything in Path() - if I understand correctly, doing so makes the output compliant with whichever OS. But I forgot to add `pathlib.` to the last line..

Comment: Besides losing the leading `/`, which is probably not what you want, what is the advantage to just doing `p.parent`?

Comment: None - I misunderstood `p.parent` :\